# oAuth chrome extension with an account other than default hangs window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am trying to implement oAuth in google chrome extension using the JavaScript SDK. I include the following library:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Here `handleClientLoad` is the function that is invoked when this library loads.

To perform the oAuth I am calling the following function:

`gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, function(authResult){`

Everything works perfectly except that when oAuth popup appears and I have 2-3 instances of google accounts logged in (i.e I am logged into multiple gmail accounts in the same browser) it opens up the primary google account. When I try to switch to a different google account in the oAuth window the oAuth never completes and window gets stuck.

I need to know what I am doing wrong and what can be a good way around to this problem. Seems that this issue only occurs with the extension. Not if I were on a web app.

P.S this is how I try to switch accounts:

[image]

Comment: Any reason why not using chrome identity? (Requires user to be signed in to chrome which is a drawback)

Comment: @ZigMandel Yes first things first to use the chrome identity the user has to be signed into the browser. And the second drawback is that the user can't switch the accounts from the oAuth window incase of chrome identity.

Comment: Before identity existed i rolled my own and remember also having a similar issue. I didnt use a library for the oauth flow. Sorry  no longer have that code.